# Browser issues : How do I check what is being sent to page (IE version 10)

Tags: asp.net, firefox, user-interface, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

I have an ASP.net website that was working fine with IE9, Mozilla, chrome but with IE 10 users have lot issues. The UI and even the functionality (like clicking on button, login/logout do not work) doesn't work well with IE10.

The IE version I have is 10.0.9200.16519.

I see few differences between the view source from IE10 and google-chrome (or even IE9) but can't understand much of it.

Where actually in the site can I check why pages sent to IE 10 browser is different from others browser or IE9?

Please suggest how can I debug further?

PS: The site works fine with IE9 and below versions of IE.

Comment: I highly doubt that a different page is being served to IE10. More likely that you've got malformed HTML, CSS, or Javascript that are causing bugs.

Comment: ASP.NET fails to identify IE10's user-agent string, and as a result can send back broken code. See [this blog on Hanselman.com](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx).

Comment: @ChristianVarga: Thanks for the reply. But HTML,CSS,Javascript are the same that are working fine in other browsers. How and where do I start debugging?

Comment: @JonathanSampson very interesting, didn't know that. That sounds like the exact problem. However, just to clarify your last statement Anirudh: just because your website works fine in one browser, it doesn't mean it will work fine in _all_ browsers. Many browser-specific bugs exist. However in this case I think Jonathan is right.

Comment: @JonathanSampson: Thanks for the blog link. Can you post your reply as an ANSWER so that I can accept it?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET fails to identify IE10's user-agent string, and as a result can send back broken code. This has been discussed in various places, but probably most notably on Scott Hanselman's blog. See the post titled [Bug and Fix: ASP.NET fails to detect IE10 causing `_doPostBack is undefined` JavaScript error or maintain FF5 scrollbar position](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

check if there is any js error,  use IE developer toolbar (F12) to debug script